# dynamic object in a project with .net 4.5 version and 3rd party assembly with .3.5 confusing system.linq Any() method inside a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, umbraco

I'm in project with version 4.5 and i also have an assembly which is compiled in 3.5 .net version.

I have this code:

```
 @* Select visible children *@
    var selection = node.Children.Where("Visible").Where("Level <= " + maxLevelForSitemap);

    @* If any items are returned, render a list *@
    if (selection.Any())
    {
//code
}
```

The problem occurs in **selection.Any()** because when i add to the project the reference to the external dll compiled with 3.5, inside the view, in runtime, I obtain an error that the method **Any()** doesn't exist because is confunsing the system.Linq from 3.5 (which doesn't have this extension method) with the 4.0.

The only way I've managed to work is if I Strongly type the object...

Is there any solution for this "dynamic linq" problem?

Comment: Um, LINQ definitely contained `Any()` in .NET 3.5... what is the compile-time type of `selection`? And what is the *exact* error message you're getting?

Comment: this is the error: 'Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContentList' does not contain a definition for 'Any'. The compile-time of selection is DynamicPublishedContentList, i'm using umbraco

Comment: And do you have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`? If you try using `if (Enumerable.Any(selection))` does that change the error message?

Comment: I did add the using system.linq statement and I obtain the same error. My guess is some configuration that i'm missing in the web.config to force the system.core do run in 4.0.

Comment: Well that really *does* sound like a guess - as I say, you should try `Enumerable.Any(selection)` and see what that does. Are you *positive* the compile-time type of `selection` is `DynamicPublishedContentList` rather than `dynamic`? (That would explain the issue, as extension methods can't be bound dynamically.)

Comment: Is dynamic yes and the Enumerable.Any() works. But what's troubling me is if i don't add the 3rd party assembly the code works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76089/discussion-between-coastpear-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: In fact, i have this problem with any extension method when i don't strongly type the object. My object has more List properties and if a do Object.propertyA.PropertyListB.Count() a still have the same problem unless i use the Enumerable.Count(Object.propertyA.PropertyListB)... Is this normal just because i add a refence to the project that was compiled in 3.5?

Comment: No, it's because the compile-time type is dynamic, I suspect, as I said before.e

Comment: And no, the same code *won't* work without 3rd party components. It's just part of dynamic...

Comment: Sorry, I think i didn't explain very well. The code works if I don't add the 3rd party assembly (the Project has .net 4.5 version), if and only I add the assembly, then the code breaks. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Well all I can repeat is that you can't call extension methods on something with a compile-time type of `dynamic`. It's not clear which 3rd party library you mean, but you can verify this very easily: `dynamic x = new int[10]; Console.WriteLine(x.Any());` will fail to compile, without any 3rd party libraries being involved...

Comment: Is this even LINQ? I'm not familiar with the syntax that would allow `.Where("Visible")`

Comment: How does `.Where("Visible")` make any sense? What is the type of `node.Children`, and does this type have a `Where` method that accepts strings?

Comment: As I thought, this isn't LINQ at all.  He's using a custom object from Umbraco called a DynamicNode, that has its own syntax that vaguely resembles LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selection returns a dynamic object (Dynamic Node) which is a custom object from umbraco. LINQ won't work on dynamic objects (easily), and all the methods you used above are umbraco's version of filtering and querying.  Umbraco also doesn't support .Any(), you should try .Count()>0 instead.